# Get all rows from database using Web Service

Tags: web-services, odoo

I want to get all details from database table using WebService in Openerp. I have seen this [link](https://doc.openerp.com/5.0/developer/6_21_web_services/) and found that by default all data can read using `read`.

I have done using a set of ids and shown their details. Is there any ways by which i can get details of entire table.

Here is my code

```
Object ids1[] = { 1,2,3,4 };
Object[] params2 = { "city", "name","email", "create_date",
"write_date" };
Vector<Object> arg = new Vector<Object>();

arg.add("stock");
arg.add(3);
arg.add("demo");
arg.add("res.partner.address");
arg.add("read");
arg.add(ids1);
arg.add(params2);

    Object[] ids= (Object[]) client.execute("execute", arg);

  for(int i = 0 ; i < ids.length ; i ++)
  {
     Iterator it = ((HashMap)ids[i]).entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Object[] params2 = { } I think that leaving it empty, should return you entire table.